# How to append Three String and again Seprate Three String

Tags: java, android

Greetings of the day !! I have Three String which i want to save in my Database. Lest Say

```
String a = "mike";
String b = "Michael";
String c = "Andrew";
```

I want to save three name into database and when I get back that data from JSON I want to separate three names.. For adding Purpose I did like.

```
String complete_tagged_value = a+b+c;
```

And my output is like

```
mikeMichaelAndrew
```

How to seprate three names .. Please suggest me...

Comment: `String complete_tagged_value = String.format("%s %s %s", a, b, c);`

Comment: use this String complete_tagged_value = a+" "+b+" "+c;

Comment: Hi @MohammedAoufZOUAG please explain in few words.. and thank you for your quick response

Comment: What about saving the data as JSON to database, and while retrieving convert back to separate data.

Comment: Have a look at [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Storing three values (names) in one field of a database is very bad practice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before saving the string to DB, while concatinating the strings, do like this

```
String delimitter="_";
StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
buffer.append(a);
buffer.append(delimitter);
buffer.append(b);
buffer.append(delimitter);
buffer.append(b);
```

While retrieving back separate these strings with same delimitter

```
String[] parts = string.split(delimitter);
```

Comment: Thank you Harry .. Let me Implement and I will update to you very soon. Thnxx again for your help

Comment: Hi Harry.. My Data is like here 


String delimitter="_";
   StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
   buffer.append(acti_id_to_save);
   buffer.append(delimitter);
   buffer.append(note_tag_first);
   buffer.append(delimitter);
   buffer.append(note_tag_details);
   ListNotes.add(StringNote);
   ListNotes.add("6");
   ListNotes.add(NotesId);
   if (stringFilnameNote.equals("N.A"))
    stringFilnameNote = "";
   ListNotes.add(stringFilnameNote);

   if (stringFilnameNote.equals(""))
    stringFilnameNote = "N.A";
   if (note_tag_details !=null)
    ListNotes.add(buffer);

Comment: @kitkat so what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: All that data I had to set into List. so when I was addinf Data it was showing Error..

Comment: listNode.add(buffer);

Comment: post your full logic then only can understand

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to choose a special character and place it between the names, for example

```
String sc= "$";

String a = "mike";
String b = "Michael";
String c = "Andrew";

String complete_tagged_value = a + sc + b + sc + c;
```

---

When you get your string back from the database just do something like this:

```
String complete_tagged_value = (...) (Get content from database)

String[] tokens = complete_tagged_value.split(sc);

String a = tokens[0];
String b = tokens[1];
String c = tokens[2];
```

Comment: Hi @Lourenco.. It worked like charm.. Thnxx brother.,,,

Comment: No problem ;) Good luck with your project

Answer (score -1):

You can call split() of String class to seprate these three names,on the basis of uppercase letter is appear.

code is here

```
 String s = "mikeMichaelAndrew";


  String[] r = s.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
```

Comment: Please try to give more detailed answer.